In boxplot, one of the categories (x-axis) doesn't show the range, it only shows median and outliers
I create a boxplot. I have two categorical variables, 'class' (ENVST 3210, ENVST 2050, and ENVST 555# - x-axis) and 'High Impact' (these are basically number of high impact learning experiences, viz, 0:none, 1:one experience, 2:two experiences, 3:three or more, - y -axis). I want to see the variation in high impact learning for each 'class'. I know in boxplot the y-axis need to be a continuous variable - so I converted 'HighImpact' to a numeric variable. The boxplot works, but for one of 'class' category - ENVST3210, the boxplot is not showing the range, it only shows the median and outliers. I am not sure why that is happening. Any help with this is hugely appreciated.
this is my data
This is the code I ran:
#Variable 'Class' from Q5

Dataforthesis <- Dataforthesis %>%
  mutate(Class = case_when(Q5 == "ENVST 2050" ~ "ENVST 2050",
                           Q5 == "ENVST 3210" ~ "ENVST 3210",
                           Q5 == "ENVST 555#" ~ "ENVST 555#"))


Dataforthesis <- Dataforthesis %>%
  mutate(Class = factor(Class,
                        levels = c("ENVST 2050",
                                   "ENVST 3210",
                                   "ENVST 555#")))
#Variable HighImpact from Q10_1

Dataforthesis <- Dataforthesis %>%
  mutate(HighImpact = case_when(Q10_1 == "0" ~ 0,
                           Q10_1 == "1" ~ 1,
                           Q10_1 == "2" ~ 2,
                           Q10_1 == "3" ~ 3))
boxplot(Dataforthesis$HighImpact ~ Dataforthesis$Class, 
        xlab = "Class",
        ylab ="High Impact")

You will notice in the image below, that boxplot for 'ENVST 3210 category is not showing:


Welcome to SO! This might happen when a large proportion of your data falls into one category. Consider e.g. set.seed(1); data.frame(x = sample(-1:1, 100, replace = TRUE, prob = c(.1, .8, .1))) |> boxplot()

@stefan has, I suspect, nailed the issue.  But we can't be certain without easy access to your data.  At the moment, you're execting us to to recreate a data frame with several hundred entries by hand, before we even start to confirm our theory.  Is that reasonable?  Please add your data to your question using dput(Dataforthesis).  Please don't upload code, error messages, results or data as images for these reasons - and these.

Consider a mosaicplot instead of a boxplot since HighImpact  is really categorical.
mosaicplot(~ HighImpact + Class, data=Dataforthesis, shade = TRUE)
